# unable to send email using Magento SMTPpro extension

Tags: magento

I have installed a new SMTP extension SMTP pro for magento. When I ran schedular it display success with message "Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email_Queue" but I did not receive any mail. why?
PS: It is a problem with the SMTP extension. I did not any code for it. If there is any better solution for SMTP settings I will appreciate as core does not support SMTP and using php mail() function.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A site. If you need to debug Magento and its extensions you should post this on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: yes but I added a tag of magento and it is a part of programming.

Comment: Please post the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: any other way for setting smtp for magento emails

Comment: I have updated the question. please see above.

Comment: have you checked logs?

Comment: yes the log is when I enable ssl/tls : 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. vw7sm8206682pab.15 - gsmtp  and when select no ssl then:5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. vw7sm8206682pab.15 - gsmtp and when only ssl then: could not open socket.

Comment: @Ren : these are magento logs or server log?

Comment: magento smtp pro extension logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this extension was working before google has not increase security. This extension not working because of google security.

I was use this extension earlier that time it was working fine.

Comment: so any alternative for it? ie. how did you use SMTP for magento then?

Comment: You can use default mail server. This is working in local as well as live also.

Comment: yes but in default mail server mails are going to spam folder.

Comment: this is occur due to server not configure perfectly. You can check below link for spam issue
https://blog.amasty.com/5-steps-for-no-spam-e-mails-in-magento/

Comment: ok thanks.. I think I am working on localhost thats why its getting in spam.